# Counting multiple values in a range to group by category and making a pivot table with slicer

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I've been Googling at this for days and I can't seem to wrap my head around it and am not familiar enough to figure it out. I have a table of data. I have a list of categories with multiple codes for each category. Each row in my table has 100 columns than can have category codes in them. They can be blank or have different codes from the same category but no duplicate codes. Here is a small example

|  | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 6 | 4 | 7 |
| user2 | 6 | 5 | 8 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| user3 | 7 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 7 | 0 |
| user4 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 3 | 9 | 2 |

I am trying to make a pivot table to count the number of times codes are present for each category. Initially, I created additional columns in the data table, one for each category, that used COUNTIFs to look in all the columns per row and add up the categories. The additional columns look like this:

|  | cat1 | cat | cat3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| user2 | 6 | 5 | 8 |
| user3 | 7 | 7 | 5 |
| user4 | 1 | 4 | 7 |

So for example, if you count up all the codes belonging to cat1 for user1 (columns val1 - val100) it would be 3. The problem with this is when making my pivot table the columns are labeled "sum of" followed by category name, but more importantly, I can't make a slicer by category. I can make a slicer for one category and it lets me filter by the number of times the values appears in a row (0,1,2,3, etc).

I made another table with the codes in one column (unique) and the categories in another (not unique), but I just can't figure out how to get my pivot table working. I've been reading about adding a measure and using a DAX formula but I don't know if that's the right approach and I'm not familiar with them either. I need a pivot table because I eventually will turn it into a graph with slicers. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try to add your excel file for us to check.

Include the Data Tables and your Expected Result in A Pivot Table look if it works.

Through that we could understand what kind of pivot table result you expect

Comment: You should show us at least the structure of your category table as there are different approaches to look up the category, depends on how your category table is structured.

Comment: @WIL Unfortunately I can't, due to the type of data it contains and sanitizing it would take a long time. Hopefully the example will be enough.

Comment: @TerryW I don't have a category table, which is really the issue. I've tried to make one but couldn't seem to get the right combination or wrap my head around it. Since there are 100 columns and a category can appear multiple times, I've been having a hard time figuring out how to tackle it.

Comment: In the first Table the numbers in there are Categories? and your Cat1, Cat2, are those numbers in Table 1?

Comment: @WIL Yes, the val columns contain category codes. The cat columns are a sum of how many times codes for that category appear in each row.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your only Option is to Do the CountIF at the end of the table
or Reconstruct your source Table

Like

[image]

and then you pivot that like this

[image]

Lastly you can pivot that base on your second table

[image]

Your second Option is to